# Loop a Volley request

Tags: loops, for-loop, request, android-volley

I want to repeat a volley request more than one time.
Something like:

```
For (int i=0;i<10;i++){

RequestA{
TextView.setText(TextView.getText + JsonArray[i].toString);
}

}
```

When i run the program the FOR loop 10 times but the Volley request just one time with i=9, so in the TextView print just the content of the JsonArray[i=9].
So my question is: why also the Volley Request doesn't loop 10 times?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you use volley. But, i believe the volley does loop 10 times. The reason why you only see the JsonArray[i=9] is because you are overriding the value in textView. Instead of using textView, try using log to get the value and read from logcat.